# iPhone - SVProgressHUD - Can not get to appear on UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, nsprogressindicator

I am using the SVProgressHUD progress indicator, and it works very well most of the time.

I am having some issues with it not appearing as expected in certain situations, however.

For example, I would like to show the indicator when I click a button on a view.  This button launches a synch call to a web service.  At the end of the svc call, the SVProgressHUD indicator window is removed.

What is happening is - the progress window pops up and disappears immediately **after** the svc call finishes.. even though my code to display the SVProgressHUD window is the first line in my 'buttonPressed' action.

I think there are some UIView concepts I am missing here... any insight?

Thanks

Comment: Needs more information on how you're displaying the progress indicator.  Also you can get in touch with @samvermette on Twitter to ask specific questions about his control.

Comment: I am just using [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Sending Move"]; as the first line in my action.  It just doesn't appear until the entire action is complete.  I'll contact Sam and see what I am missing.. I just think there is something I am inherently not understanding about how/when UIViews are rendered.

Comment: It could be because your action is running on the main thread and the hud isn't able to get rendered before the action clogs up the main thread.  Are you running in a background thread, or a main thread?

Comment: That was my issue.  I used GCD to force the hud into the main thread, and it works perfect.  Thanks for the input.  If you want to stick your comments in an answer.. I will gladly mark as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't attempt to show user interface elements on a background thread.  If you're in a background thread, access the main thread to update your interface.